# No abre el cuadro de dialogo cuando pulso el botón

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo la siguiente aplicación:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
        QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
        QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton)


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(581, 556)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(113, 80, 81, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.EditText1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.EditText1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(112, 98, 300, 20))
        self.EditText1.setObjectName("EditText1")

        self.Edittext2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.Edittext2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(112, 153, 300, 20))
        self.Edittext2.setObjectName("Edittext2")

        self.SaveEXEButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.SaveEXEButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(418, 152, 75, 23))
        self.SaveEXEButton.setObjectName("SaveEXEButton")
        self.SaveEXEButton.clicked.connect(self.SaveFile)

        self.CloseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.CloseButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.CloseButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 247, 75, 23))
        self.CloseButton.setObjectName("CloseButton")


        self.EmbeddedConvert = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(302, 193, 106, 17))
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setObjectName("EmbeddedConvert")

        self.NormalConvert = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.NormalConvert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(114, 193, 113, 17))
        self.NormalConvert.setObjectName("NormalConvert")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(113, 137, 80, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.ConvertExeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.ConvertExeButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.ConvertExeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 247, 75, 23))
        self.ConvertExeButton.setObjectName("ConvertExeButton")

        self.Memo = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.Memo.setEnabled(True)
        self.Memo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 299, 391, 192))
        self.Memo.setObjectName("Memo")


        self.OpenPyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.OpenPyButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(418, 97, 75, 23))
        self.OpenPyButton.setObjectName("OpenPyButton")
        self.OpenPyButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenFiles)


        self.BarraLateral = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(Form)
        self.BarraLateral.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(479, 299, 17, 192))
        self.BarraLateral.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.BarraLateral.setObjectName("BarraLateral")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def OpenFiles(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Py Files.....",self.EditText1.text(),"Python Files (*.py)")
        if fileName:
            self.EditText1.setText(fileName)    


    def SaveFile(self):    
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
            "Save as Exe File...",
            self.Edittext2.text(),
            "All Files (*);;Exe Files (*.exe)")
        if fileName:
            self.Edittext2.setText(fileName)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Load File ..."))
        self.SaveEXEButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Browser"))
        self.CloseButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Cerrar"))
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setText(_translate("Form", "Python Embedded"))
        self.NormalConvert.setText(_translate("Form", " Normal Convert"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Save File ..."))
        self.ConvertExeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Convert Now"))
        self.OpenPyButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Browser"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El problema es que cuando hago click en cualquiera de los dos botones <kbd>Browser</kbd> no abre el cuadro de dialogo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu clase `Ui_Form` no es un widget, por lo tanto `self` en `SaveFile` y `OpenFiles` no es una instancia de `QWidget`, por lo que no es un padre válido para  `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName` y `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName`. Deberías pasar como padre `Form` (tu instancia de `QWidget`) no `self`.

No obstante, te aconsejo no tocar la clase generada por pyuic, crea tu propia clase que herede de `QWidget` y de `Ui_Form` y agrega en ella lo que quieras como los slots:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
        QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
        QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton)


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(581, 556)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(113, 80, 81, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.EditText1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.EditText1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(112, 98, 300, 20))
        self.EditText1.setObjectName("EditText1")

        self.Edittext2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.Edittext2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(112, 153, 300, 20))
        self.Edittext2.setObjectName("Edittext2")

        self.SaveEXEButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.SaveEXEButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(418, 152, 75, 23))
        self.SaveEXEButton.setObjectName("SaveEXEButton")

        self.CloseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.CloseButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.CloseButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(178, 247, 75, 23))
        self.CloseButton.setObjectName("CloseButton")


        self.EmbeddedConvert = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(302, 193, 106, 17))
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setObjectName("EmbeddedConvert")

        self.NormalConvert = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(Form)
        self.NormalConvert.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(114, 193, 113, 17))
        self.NormalConvert.setObjectName("NormalConvert")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(113, 137, 80, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.ConvertExeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.ConvertExeButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.ConvertExeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 247, 75, 23))
        self.ConvertExeButton.setObjectName("ConvertExeButton")

        self.Memo = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.Memo.setEnabled(True)
        self.Memo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 299, 391, 192))
        self.Memo.setObjectName("Memo")


        self.OpenPyButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.OpenPyButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(418, 97, 75, 23))
        self.OpenPyButton.setObjectName("OpenPyButton")

        self.BarraLateral = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(Form)
        self.BarraLateral.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(479, 299, 17, 192))
        self.BarraLateral.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.BarraLateral.setObjectName("BarraLateral")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def OpenFiles(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Py Files.....",self.EditText1.text(),"Python Files (*.py)")
        if fileName:
            self.EditText1.setText(fileName)    


    def SaveFile(self):    
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
            "Save as Exe File...",
            self.Edittext2.text(),
            "All Files (*);;Exe Files (*.exe)")
        if fileName:
            self.Edittext2.setText(fileName)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Load File ..."))
        self.SaveEXEButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Browser"))
        self.CloseButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Cerrar"))
        self.EmbeddedConvert.setText(_translate("Form", "Python Embedded"))
        self.NormalConvert.setText(_translate("Form", " Normal Convert"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Save File ..."))
        self.ConvertExeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Convert Now"))
        self.OpenPyButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Browser"))



class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.OpenPyButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenFiles)
        self.SaveEXEButton.clicked.connect(self.SaveFile)

    def OpenFiles(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Py Files.....",self.EditText1.text(),"Python Files (*.py)")
        if fileName:
            self.EditText1.setText(fileName)    

    def SaveFile(self):    
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
            "Save as Exe File...",
            self.Edittext2.text(),
            "All Files (*);;Exe Files (*.exe)")
        if fileName:
            self.Edittext2.setText(fileName)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Si en un futuro modificas la interfaz con QtDesigner no teendrás que modificar nada más.